# Center manifold theorem and case of all zero eigenvalues

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, stability

Is the center manifold theorem applicable if say for a planar (2D) system of non-linear ODE, the stability matrix has both eigenvalues zero? Of course, there is only one eigenvector.

If not, what is the way to approach such a problem?

Comment: Of course the center manifold theorem is applicable to this case. It just does not reduce the system beyond what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with a two dimensional center manifold. If you have a planar system with an equilibrium at which the Jacobian has two zero eigenvalues but only one linearly independent eigenvector, then you may have a [Bogdanov-Takens (double-zero bifurcation)](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bogdanov-Takens_bifurcation) in your system.